# Multiply form value by X and display total in html

Tags: javascript, forms

```
 <form>
 Chapter 1 - Please enter how many copys you would like <br>
 <input type="text" id="chap1"> <br><br>
 Chapter 2 - Please enter how many copys you would like <br>
 <input type="text" id="chap2"> <br><br>
 Chapter 3 - Please enter how many copys you would like <br>
 <input type="text" id="chap3"> <br><br>
 Chapter 4 - Please enter how many copys you would like <br>
 <input type="text" id="chap4"> <br><br>
 Chapter 5 - Please enter how many copys you would like <br>
 <input type="text" id="chap5"> <br><br>
  <b> Total price :  <output id = "total"> 0 </output> </b>
```

I'm trying to create a website in which you can order books by chapters, each chapter costs £2. I need it to multiply the value of the individual forms by 2 and then display this cost in the output. I would like to use java script in order to do this rather than jQuery.

I havent tried much as of yet as i cant find much on the subject, so any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/)

Comment: give little bit more explanation of your question what you want to do

Comment: i would like to be able to let the user define a number of copies that they would like e.g. chapter 1 they would enter a number and so on
then i would like it to times the numebr by the price (£2) and display a total of all the copies added together.

Comment: You can use `document.querySelectorAll("input")`, then loop though all input and  get values of required copies using `.value`. And then just do math.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    var totalChapters = document.querySelectorAll(input).value;
      totalPrice = document.getElementById('total');

    totalPrice.value  = totalChapters * 2;

   </script>


no luck unfortunatley

Comment: What is your specific question/problem? What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not a code writing service...

Answer (score 0):

```
function calc(){
    price = 2;
    fields = document.querySelectorAll("input[id^='chap']");
    tot = 0;
    for(i=0; i<fields.length; i++){
        tot += fields[i].value * price;
    }
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = tot;
}
```

This is a simple example, you can improve it

Comment: it didnt work i put it into a seperate js file and linked it in but its still not updating the total

Comment: @SamuelBaxter when the total is to be updated?
for exaple you can add a button that call the function `<input type="button" value="calc" onclick="calc()">`

Answer (score 0):

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/EyKnr/28/)

```
 <input type="text" id="chap1">
 <input type="text" id="chap2">
 <input type="text" id="chap3">
<input type="text" id="chap4"> 
<input type="text" id="chap5">
<b> Total price :  <output id = "total"> 0 </output> </b>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var text1= document.getElementById("chap1").value;
var text2= document.getElementById("chap2").value;
var text3= document.getElementById("chap3").value;
var text4= document.getElementById("chap4").value;
var text5= document.getElementById("chap5").value;
var  total=parseInt(text1)+parseInt(text2)+parseInt(text3)+parseInt(text4)+parseInt(text5);
 document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total*2.1;
 }
 </script>
```